R version 4.4.1 fails to source a file that older versions sources without problem
I have installed R version 4.4.1 on a new computer (windows 11), and try to run a program that runs without problems on other computers (with R version 4.0.2 and 4.1.0). The problematic part is (anonymized):
sendAnEmail <- function(recipient, tøpic, body="", fil){
    email <- envelope()%>%
        from("someone@gmail.com")%>%
        to(recipient)%>%
        subject(tøpic)%>%
        text_body(content=body, encoding="8bit")%>% 
        attachment(fil1)
    smtp <- server(host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        port = 587,
        username = "someone@gmail.com",
        password = "somepassword") 
    smtp(email, verbose = FALSE)
}

This is contained in a file called "test.r", which I source from console.
I tried sourcing with different encodings end got error message:
source("test.r", encoding="utf-8")

Error in source("test.r") : test.r:3:5: unexpected invalid token
2:     email <- envelope()%>%
3:      
^
Have also tried, with same result:
source("test.r") 
source("test.r", encoding="native.enc")
eval(parse("test.r", encoding="UTF-8"))
source.utf8 <- function(f){
    l <- readLines(f, encoding="UTF-8")
    eval(parse(text=l),envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
source.utf8("test.r")

And:
Sys.getlocale()

[1] "LC_COLLATE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_CTYPE=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_MONETARY=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Norwegian Bokmål_Norway.utf8"
How can I get this work?
